# Pandas: column of type str converted to tslib.Timestamp after using apply function

Tags: python, string, pandas, timespan

I was trying to filter out some duplicated data in a dataframe when something weird occurred: 'Col1' string elements were converted to Timestamp without notice. I want Col1 to continue to have string elements.

Here is the example:

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> df = DataFrame({
     'Col0': 'RR0 RR1 RR2 RR3 RR4 RR5 RR6 RR7'.split(),
     'Col1' : 'A7 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7'.split(),
     'Col2' : [
               DT.datetime(2013,1,1,13,0),
               DT.datetime(2013,1,1,13,5),
               DT.datetime(2013,10,1,20,0),
               DT.datetime(2013,10,2,10,0),
               DT.datetime(2013,10,1,20,0),
               DT.datetime(2013,10,2,10,0),
               DT.datetime(2013,12,2,12,0),
               DT.datetime(2013,12,2,14,0)
              ],
     'Col3': [1,3,5,1,8,1,9,3],
     'Col4': 'L0 L1 L0 L0 L2 L2 L3 L4'.split()})

>>> df=df[['Col0','Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4']]

>>> df
   Col0 Col1                Col2  Col3 Col4
0  RR0   A7 2013-01-01 13:00:00     1   L0
1  RR1   A1 2013-01-01 13:05:00     3   L1
2  RR2   A2 2013-10-01 20:00:00     5   L0
3  RR3   A3 2013-10-02 10:00:00     1   L0
4  RR4   A4 2013-10-01 20:00:00     8   L2
5  RR5   A5 2013-10-02 10:00:00     1   L2
6  RR6   A6 2013-12-02 12:00:00     9   L3
7  RR7   A7 2013-12-02 14:00:00     3   L4

# Filter the data of Col4 by oldest time register in Col2
>>> df2=df.groupby('Col4',group_keys=False,as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.ix[x.Col2.idxmin()])

# df was filtered but Col1 was transformed to Timespan
>>> df2
   Col0       Col1                Col2  Col3 Col4
0  RR0 2015-04-07 2013-01-01 13:00:00     1   L0
1  RR1 2015-04-01 2013-01-01 13:05:00     3   L1
2  RR4 2015-04-04 2013-10-01 20:00:00     8   L2
3  RR6 2015-04-06 2013-12-02 12:00:00     9   L3
4  RR7 2015-04-07 2013-12-02 14:00:00     3   L4
```

**Question: What is the reason for this behavior? and Is there a way to avoid this happening?**

Comment: I am not replicating your results. What veriosn of python and pandas are you using.

Comment: @MarkGraph: I'm seeing the problem using Python2.7 / Pandas version 0.15.2.

Comment: This also happens in pandas 0.16.0

Comment: Strange: I am using pandas 0.16.0 on python 2.7; and I get the right answer.

Comment: I'm running python 3.4 and numpy 1.9.1

Comment: @MarkGraph I'm using python 2.7.6 and pandas 0.15.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas attempts to identify column data that is datetime-like, and if so, convert it that column to a datetime dtype. It uses `dateutil.parser.parse` under the hood. Unfortunately, `dateutils.parser.parse` recognizes some strings like `A7` as a date:

```
In [28]: import dateutil.parser as DP
In [29]: DP.parse('A7')
Out[31]: datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 7, 0, 0)
```

even though (in this case) it was not intended as a date.

Therefore, to work around the problem, you could collect the `idxmin`s, and the select rows from `df` using `df.iloc`:

```
idx = df.groupby('Col4')['Col2'].idxmin()
df2 = df.iloc[idx]
```

yields

```
  Col0 Col1                Col2  Col3 Col4
0  RR0   A7 2013-01-01 13:00:00     1   L0
1  RR1   A1 2013-01-01 13:05:00     3   L1
4  RR4   A4 2013-10-01 20:00:00     8   L2
6  RR6   A6 2013-12-02 12:00:00     9   L3
7  RR7   A7 2013-12-02 14:00:00     3   L4
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked! Is this a implementation problem of pandas or the apply function that I was using?

Comment: The problem also happens with string of type 'M#' and 'T#'

Comment: Yes, I think it is a bug in the implementation.
My personal opinion is that it is just a bad idea for Pandas to attempt any
implicit conversion to datetimes. *Explicit is better than implicit*. However, a lot of people seem to like pandas because of its convenience, and part of this convenience is gained by Pandas attempting to just do the right thing for you.

Comment: One last question: Is there a way to force columns data type from scratch when importing the data or defining the dataframe? I know there is a dtype but I was not able to make it work specifying each column type as in R colClasses. [_Should I start another discussion thread?_]

Comment: The answer is (probably) yes, but the details depend on how you are importing the data (from csv? a database? a hdf5 file? etc.) Please start a new question with a sample of the input and the desired output.